# Android - view above imageView appears on some devices but doesn't appear on Nexus 4

Tags: android, xml, android-layout, view

I have this layout that contains an image view and a black view. On some devices (Samsung Galaxy S2 for example) the black view is ok, but when I tested the app on a Nexus 4 the black view was invisible. Any ideas why is this happening?

https://www.dropbox.com/s/szuptgebsi3ee8e/Screenshot%202013-12-17%2012.27.26.png

This is the xml:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical" 
    android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
    android:scaleType="fitXY"
    >

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/categoryPhoto"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:scaleType="fitXY"
        android:src="@drawable/top_attractions" />

    <View
        android:id="@+id/dark_gray_overlay"
        android:layout_width="180dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/categoryPhoto"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:background="#363636" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to add following code in onCreate() method:

```
(findViewById(R.id.dark_gray_overlay)).bringToFront();
```